# Swift_TransportException Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [Connection timed out #110] in yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, swiftmailer

i am trying to send mail via swift mailer using yii2 but it is getting this error.
Swift_TransportException Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [Connection timed out #110]

when i send mail using local host than it is sending but when i used the these settings on my test server than it is not sending the mail.

```
<?php
   return [
'components' => [
    'db' => [
        'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
        'dsn' => 'mysql:host=db553769847.db.1and1.com;dbname=db553769847',
        'username' => 'myusername',
        'password' => 'mypassword',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
    ],
    'mailer' => [
         'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
        'useFileTransport'=>false,
         'viewPath' => '@common/mail',
         'transport' => [
             'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport', 
             'host'=>'smtp.gmail.com',                
             'username' => 'myuserename',
             'password' =>'mypassword',
             'port'=>'587',
             'encryption'=>'tls',

         ],

     ],
   ],
  ];
```